# PySimpleGui show image in popup

Tags: python, image, popup, display, pysimplegui

I want to display an image in a popup. Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried image=(path) but it's not working ...

```
sg.popup_no_buttons('Text', title='Über uns', text_color=('#F7F6F2'), keep_on_top=True)
```

Currently:

[image]

Target:

[image]

Comment: you may try `image=sg.Image(path)` instead.

Comment: @tromgy not working ... :(

Comment: Actually, your approach was correct, and my suggestion was wrong. What kind of error do you see exactly?

Comment: @tromgy I get like unlimited errors and then the program crashes. Some of the last errors: imgur.com/a/qxeGuaT

Comment: Maybe - as always - a MacOS thing?

Answer (score 3):

Confirm version of your tkinter not 8.5, especially for MacOS users, tkinter 8.5 does not support PNG image.

With option `image` in `sg.popup_no_buttons`, you can add image into popup.

Value of option `image`

- `str` for image filename (GIF or PNG), or
- `bytes` for `raw` or `Base64` of image.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.popup_no_buttons('Text', title='Über uns', text_color=('#F7F6F2'), keep_on_top=True, image=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_IDEA)
sg.popup_no_buttons('Text', title='Über uns', text_color=('#F7F6F2'), keep_on_top=True, image="D:/1.png")
```

Image not aligned to center for `sg.popup_no_buttons`, you may create a popup by yourself. Demo code as following,

```py
from textwrap import wrap
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(title, filename, message, width=70):

    lines = list(map(lambda line:wrap(line, width=width), message.split('\n')))
    height = sum(map(len, lines))
    message = '\n'.join(map('\n'.join, lines))

    layout = [
        [sg.Image(filename=filename, expand_x=True)],
        [sg.Text(message, size=(width, height), justification='center', expand_x=True)]
    ]

    sg.Window(title, layout, keep_on_top=True, modal=True).read(close=2000)

popup('Über uns', 'D:/emoji.png', 'message')

message = """
Python is an easy to learn, powerful programming language.
It has efficient high-level data structures and a simple but effective approach to object-oriented programming.
Python’s elegant syntax and dynamic typing, together with its interpreted nature, make it an ideal language for scripting and rapid application development in many areas on most platforms.
""".strip()

popup('Über uns', 'D:/emoji.png', message)
```

Comment: Both are not working and I get the same error message: imgur.com/a/qxeGuaT > Is it an MacOS thing?

Comment: tkinter 8.5 not support PNG image, you may check it by `import tkinter as tk` and `tk.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')`.

Comment: If possible, try to post what the failure, not just say it doesn't work, or it failed. Maybe also what environment, like your platform, python, library, also version.

Comment: Indeed it is version 8.5.9. How do I upgrade with python3? And btw. I send a image of the errors, watch the imgur.com link :3

Comment: Not sure how to upgrade it, but you can refer following link, it may help https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: if that of any help, this minimalistic virtual environment worked for me (on macOS):
Python 3.9.1
pip         20.3.3
PySimpleGUI 4.47.0
setuptools  51.3.3
wheel       0.36.2